# Css Li Sqaure 4x4 Box Text Align

Tags: css, hyperlink, html-lists

I came really far, but now im totally stuck. I created a 4x4 Li Box as a tiny navigation menu. If you hover over one of the four Boxes two things happen:

1.-A Preview Image of the site (just an img) is popping up.
2.-The Box Li a text is popping up. (The Link Label.)

At the moment the text is perfectly centered in the middle of its own square. How could I move them? (I need to move them left/right for a few pixels.)

```css
ul.square-menu {
font-size:0;
list-style-type: none;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
width: 400px;
margin: 40px auto;
}

ul.square-menu li{
float: left;
margin:0px; 
}

ul.square-menu li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 90px 70px;
color: #fffefa;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 150%;
width: 60px;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);

}

ul.square-menu li a.slink-x {
background-image: url(leftup.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}

ul.square-menu li a.slink-y {
background-image: url(rightup.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}

ul.square-menu li a.slink-z {
background-image: url(leftdown.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}

ul.square-menu li a.slink-a {
background-image: url(rightdown.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}
ul.square-menu li a.slink-x:hover {
background-image: url(leftupactive.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}
ul.square-menu li a.slink-y:hover {
background-image: url(rightupactive.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}
ul.square-menu li a.slink-z:hover {
background-image: url(leftdownactive.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}
ul.square-menu li a.slink-a:hover {
background-image: url(rightdownactive.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}

ul.square-menu li a:hover {
font-size:26px;

}

.PolOne {
 visibility: inherit;
 z-index: 1;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: -350px;
 margin-top: -200px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 9px 10px 19px 0px rgba(214,214,214,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 9px 10px 19px 0px rgba(214,214,214,1);
box-shadow: 9px 10px 19px 0px rgba(214,214,214,1);

}

.slink-x:not(:hover) + .PolOne {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.PolTwo {
 visibility: inherit;
 z-index: 1;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 300px;
 margin-top: -200px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -15px 10px 19px 0px rgba(214,214,214,1);
-moz-box-shadow: -15px 10px 19px 0px rgba(214,214,214,1);
box-shadow: -15px 10px 19px 0px rgba(214,214,214,1);
 
}

.slink-y:not(:hover) + .PolTwo {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.PolThree {
 visibility: inherit;
 z-index: 1;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: -325px;
 margin-top: -200px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 10px 19px 0px rgba(214,214,214,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 9px 10px 19px 0px rgba(214,214,214,1);
box-shadow: 9px 10px 19px 0px rgba(214,214,214,1);
 
}

.slink-z:not(:hover) + .PolThree {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.PolFour {
 visibility: inherit;
 z-index: 1;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 250px;
 margin-top: -200px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -15px 10px 19px 0px rgba(214,214,214,1);
-moz-box-shadow: -15px 10px 19px 0px rgba(214,214,214,1);
box-shadow: -15px 10px 19px 0px rgba(214,214,214,1);

}

.slink-a:not(:hover) + .PolFour {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul class="square-menu" padding-top="50px">

     <li>
      <a target="_parent" href="#" class="slink-x" >News</a>
                    <div class="PolOne"> <img src="one.png"></div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a target="_parent" href="#" class="slink-y">Kalender</a>
                        <div class="PolTwo"> <img src="two.png"></div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a target="_parent" href="#" class="slink-z">Kontakt</a>
                        <div class="PolThree"> <img src="three.png"></div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a target="_parent" href="#" class="slink-a">Anfahrt</a>
                        <div class="PolFour"> <img src="four.png"></div>
     </li>
     <br style="clear:both;"/>
    
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: The output of the snippet is not very informative. E.g. there are no squares visible.